# Redirect standard error to a variable in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I would like to script a dcdiag test to alert me if it finds any errors. I thought I may able to do this in PowerShell by...

```
$test = dcdiag 2>$err
```

I don't have any errors from dcdiag at the moment, so I couldn't test that directly, but I wrote another PowerShell script to throw an exception, hoping I could test this method using that script. This didn't work using the method above so I opted for:

```
try {
    $test = dcdiag
}
catch { 
    $err = $_.Exception.Message
}
```

It worked for my test case, but I don't know if this will pick up standard error from dcdiag.

How should I best achieve standard error redirect to a variable in PowerShell given I would like to use it with dcdiag?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`try...catch` wouldn't help in this case.

You might want to do:

```
$test = dcdiag 2>&1
$err = $test | ?{$_.gettype().Name -eq "ErrorRecord"}
if($err){
    # Error has occurred
}
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't say in the original question; is it possible to keep both stdout and stderr? i.e $test = stdout and $err = stderr?

Comment: @Ablue - `$test` will have both, that is why I am filtering out the error to `$err`.

Comment: Make sure $ErrorActionPreference is not set to "SilentlyContinue". When it is the errors stream is not available.

Comment: @cmcginty actually $ErrorActionPreference should be set to "Continue". Using SilentlyContinue will only capture stdout as stderr will be completely removed (at least on powershell 5)

Comment: @Simon Correct, I said DO NOT use SilentlyContinue.

Comment: Reverse the filter to get stdout without the error (but still capture stderr) `$test | ?{$_.gettype().Name -ne "ErrorRecord"}`