# Write stderror to a file using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, search, stderr

How do I capture error messages from a PowerShell-launched command in a text file?

I searched the Internet for a while and found that supposedly, I should be able to do something like `""C:\UniServer\usr\local\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe" -h 192.0.2.0 -u"backup" -p"longComplicatedPassword" --all-databases >"C:\Users\Zian\MySQL Database Backups\20130118221525.sql" 2>"C:\users\zian\desktop\MySQL Backup Error.txt""` to direct the output to output.txt and the errors to errors.txt but when I try to run the command, I get the following error:

```
cmd.exe : The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
At C:\Users\Zian\Desktop\Untitled1.ps1:27 char:4
+ cmd <<<<  /c $command 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (The filename, d...x is incorrect.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Furthermore, if I try to run the command without everything starting at "2", then the command executes correctly and output.txt catches the right output.

I looked at [Redirect stderr to variable in powershell](https://serverfault.com/questions/340711/redirect-stderr-to-variable-in-powershell) but it wasn't helpful because the answer to that question suggests capturing the entire output and filtering it in memory. In my case, I am backing up every database on a computer and since the databases won't fit in my laptop's RAM, I cannot use the question's solution.

I also found tantalizing suggestions about using `$err = @(command goes here)` but with no information on what to do other than simply inserting that line of text. I tried to utilize the search function on Serverfault with the string "`@()`", but it did not return any results.

What can I do to get the error messages into errors.txt?

Comment: It may help if you interpolate "big blob of text" for us so that we can test. Powershell doesn't need to know about stdout/stderr from the external command as they should be handled, well, *externally* and redirect their streams accordingly.  For instance, in PS a simple `cmd /c "dir . >output.txt 2>errors.txt"` works as expected, producing an `output.txt` which contains the `dir` list, and a zero-byte `errors.txt`.

Comment: Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1215260/80161

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As jscott pointed out, the command works. I simply forgot to add in enough back-ticked quotation marks.

The solution then, is to make sure there are the quotation marks around the entire line of text after cmd /c.